# What component should fetch data in angular 1.5, 2, react? root or child?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, reactjs, components

I'm working at new project with angular 1.5 (starting component path of building), but question is not about angular, it's about design pattern.

Lets say i have complex website with this main page:

```
<header></header>
<sidebar-left></sidebar-left>
<sidebar-right></sidebar-rigth>
<mainSection>
  <news></news>
  <movie-list></movie-list>
  <random-quotes></random-quotes>
</mainSection>
<footer></footer>
```

**News**, **movie list** and **quotes** blocks displaying data from server. Each from their own method/api. So WHO is responsible for fetching data? Should `main` component fetch data and pass it to children? Or `news`, `movieList` and `randomQuotes` components should fetch data by itself?

1) `Main` component fetching data map it to scope and pass to children

```
<mainSection>
  <news items="$ctrl.news"></news>
  <movie-list items="$ctrl.movies"></movie-list>
  <random-quotes items="$ctrl.quotes"></random-quotes>
</mainSection>
```

**VS**

2) Every child component should fetch data

```
class MovieListController {
  constructor(MovieService) {
    this.movieService = MovieService;
  }
  $onInit() {
    this.movies = [];
    this.movieService.getAll().then(response => this.movies = response);
  }
}

export const movieList = {
  template: '<movie-item ng-repeat="movie in $ctrl.movies"></movie-item>',
  controller: MovieListController,
};
```

Comment: If the `Main` component fetches the movie, you wouldn't be able to use your child components anywhere else without duplicating this functionality.

Comment: I would highly recommend to go through [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.ibuwgi6sz), both approaches has its own benifits. but I would prefer the 1st over 2nd as its clearly separates out our code into `stateful` component is wrapping up `stateless` component, also go through [this article](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.vjlkvtc5b) as well..

Comment: @Sven exactly! only this stopping me from choosing 1st method.

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks for the reply and links to articles!

Comment: Sooooo, if i want to reuse exactly same component, i should choose 2nd way. But if i want to reuse component with another set of data, i should choose 1st. And if i don't plan to reuse component i should choose 1st to separate stateful from stateless. Am i right?